# Regex PHP remove all float numbers

Tags: php, regex

Learning regex in PHP. Here's my code:

```
 header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
 $lines = file('datatest.txt');
 $lines = preg_grep("/word/", $lines); //finds words that I need, including numbers
 $lines = preg_replace('/\d/', '', $lines); //replaces all numbers with ''
 foreach ($lines as $name) {
    echo "$name";
}
```

I have a lined text, every line starts with nubmer, for example:

```
1.1. Name
2.0. Name2
2.3. Name3
```

Removed digits, but comma stays, now it looks like this:

```
.. Name
.. Name2
.. Name3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$lines = preg_replace('/[\d.]+/', '', $lines); //replaces all numbers with ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: This will remove numbers and dot only from the starting of the string

```
$lines = preg_replace('/^\s*[\d\.]+/', '', $lines);
```